# Make github use perldoc to display readme document

Tags: perl, github

Can I configure github to display readme document from the perldoc ? The module (.pm) was uploaded there, I just want github to make some output that was generated from e.g `perldoc module.pm`, automatically ( I shouldn't be changing readme.md myself all the time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github would automatically handle a "README.pod" file, [according to their documentation](https://github.com/github/markup). Creating and maintaining README.pod is up to you. You could consider using some local automation tools to maintain it, if you don't want to maintain it by hand.

There are some benefits to maintaining the README separately. For example, a Perl module's POD usually doesn't contain installation instructions, but those would be one of the first things you would expect to find in README file.

Comment: I typically have a README/README.pod that is meant to be distributed and then a README.md file that I strip from the CPAN releases that's just for information about the Github project itself.